# (discord.py) impersonating another user

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been playing around with Dadbot on a discord server, and he has a command that basically impersonates another user and says something embarrassing. I want to try this out on my own discord bot in python, but i have now idea how and i can't find any tutorials on it. I also have little experience with python and the dicord api and can only make basic commands. I heard it uses a webhook but i don't know what that is or how to use it. If anyone could teach me how or at least give a link to a proper tutorial i would appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By creating a webhook with the user's name or another user you use the command to "act" as, will create a Discord webhook with those details, then deletes the webhook, but keeps the message.

A webhook is a communication type that can be used to access & automate your messages to send data updates to your Discord text channels.

In this case, when sending the message from the command, the user appears as a bot, but everything else is from the user. NQN bot uses this exact method

```
@client.command()
async def impersonate(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, message=None):

        if message == None:
                await ctx.send(f'Who do you want to impersonate?')
                return

        webhook = await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name=member.name)
        await webhook.send(
            str(message), username=member.name, avatar_url=member.avatar_url)

        webhooks = await ctx.channel.webhooks()
        for webhook in webhooks:
                await webhook.delete()
```